# Pourquoi les néoverbes sont-ils du premier groupe ?

Tags: néologismes, verbes, conjugaison

La plupart des néoverbes (néologisme personnel désignant un néologisme verbal) sont du premier groupe, on peut par exemple citer

> **Faxer**, **textoter**, **podcaster** (ou son *infamous* équivalent **baladodiffuser**), **taser**, **chatter**, **wikifier**…

La langue française a certes une majorité de verbes du premier groupe, mais y a-t-il une autre raison à cette écrasante majorité ?

Question bonus : existe-t-il des néoverbes du deuxième ou du troisième groupe?

Comment: Un cas intéressant est celui des mots finissant avec le son i, qui devraient devenir assez naturellement des verbes du 2nd groupe. Est-ce que ça arrive souvent ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dans toutes les langues flexionnelles la tendance naturelle est d'assigner aux verbes nouvellement créés le système de conjugaison dominant, c'est à dire le système de conjugaison *régulier*.

Si par exemple j'ai besoin de créer un verbe pour signifier que l'on tire un verbe d'un substantif, je vais créer tout naturellement le verbe "verbiser" plutôt que "verboir" ou "verbir" car il y a déjà un morphème tout prêt pour cette opération: "-iser".

Je ne suis pas totalement certain que cette théorie s'applique bien au français vu le nombre de verbes qui sont irréguliers pour des raisons de pure évolution phonologique, mais dans le cas des langues germaniques par exemple on peut énoncer que les verbes irréguliers sont pour la plupart des verbes d'usage quotidien qui ont été réguliers dans des systèmes de conjugaison antérieurs maintenant obsolètes.  Comme ces verbes sont très utilisés ils évoluent plus lentement que le reste des verbes et conservent leurs caractéristiques irrégulières.

En allemand comme en anglais et dans les autres langues germaniques, on distingue les verbes forts et les verbes faibles.  La conjugaison des verbes forts respecte les règles très anciennes de l'[ablaut indo européen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut)  décrites par [Jacob Grimm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Grimm) parce que c'est la conjugaison régulière ancestrale.  Les verbes plus récents par contre suivent la conjugaison faible.

Le nombre des verbes irréguliers décroit... progressivement même s'il y a des cas marginaux [comme catch](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=catch) qui passe de régulier français à irrégulier anglais.

Dans le cas du français, les choses sont plus complexes car l'ablaut indo-européen (le terme technique est *apophonie*) est moins prononcé en latin qu'en grec et si les quatre conjugaisons du latin se sont réduites à trois groupes en français c'est surtout parce que le troisième groupe contient tout ce qui ne rentre pas dans les deux premiers.  Il ne possède cependant pas, à la différence des deux premiers, de modèle de conjugaison spécifique associé.

Comment: Une réponse de linguiste, j'aime :)

Comment: J'aurais dit _verbifier_.

Answer (score 13):

Je pense que c'est essentiellement parce que le premier groupe est le cas majoritaire ; c'est le cas régulier, et les nouveaux mots ont fortement tendance à être réguliers. On peut dire que le deuxième groupe est lui aussi régulier, mais en quelque sorte moins, parce qu'il est moins fréquent.

Il y a peut-être aussi une raison phonologique et étymologique poussant au premier groupe plutôt qu'au deuxième : la finale `-ir` provient toujours d'une finale en `-i`, alors que la finale `-er` est neutre. Quant au troisième groupe, il est irrégulier (donc ne convient guère à des néologismes : qui sauf son auteur saurait le conjuguer ?) et regroupe des verbes qui ont en général subi une longue évolution.

J'ai regardé rapidement les résultats d'une [recherche Google](http://www.google.fr/search?q=%22n%C3%A9overbe%22&hl=fr#q=%22n%C3%A9overbe%22&hl=fr), qui trouve une majorité écrasante de néoverbes du premier groupe. (Cette recherche est évidemment fortement biaisée en faveur des gens qui utilisent le mot « néoverbe », mais je ne pense pas que cela change la conclusion.) Je n'ai trouvé que deux exemples qui ne sont pas du premier groupe (sur une cinquantaine de néoverbes distincts) :

- [*Plussoir*](http://forum.lemansfc.fr/showthread.php?p=173387), signifiant « appuyer frénétiquement sur la touche `+` du clavier » sous le clavier de [jarjar](http://forum.lemansfc.fr/member.php?s=5cfb9fcf4f2fdcdec7d71e87b786debe&u=1679), et plus précisément être d'accord avec un message sur un forum (et éventuellement le marquer physiquement). Au passage, je proposerais bien ce verbe, qui a même fait son entrée dans le très honorable [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plussoir), pour traduire *upvote* sur Stack Exchange (avec comme antonyme *moinsoir*).
- Sur le blog de l'[Académie des verbes qui manquent](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/), *académir*, création de David Chassagne signifiant « agir comme une académie ». Sa façon d'écrire démontre un certain malaise avec ce verbe, puisqu'il éprouve le besoin de le confiner entre des guillemets dans son article [« Néoverbons un peu ! »](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/neoverbons-un-peu/), contrairement à d'autres comme *impertiner* ou *béabaser*.

L'Académie des verbes qui manquent répertorie de nombreux néoverbes, pour la plupart du premier groupe. Il y a quand même quelques verbes du deuxième groupe, comme [*vaillir*](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/vaillir/), [*ninir*](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/ninir/) ou [*kiwir*](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/kiwir/), tous construits sur un radical terminé par `-i` ; ainsi que des verbes du troisième groupe, comme [*samedichoir*](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/samedichoir/) (construit sur le verbe préexistant *choir*), [*surmoir*](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/surmoir/) (construit sur une racine en `-oi`), [*samedire*](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/samedire/) (construit sur *dire* et un jeu de mot avec *médire*) ou encore [*queuedepoissondre*](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/queuedepoissondre/) (dont l'imparfait serait *il queuedepoissonait*, ce qui me paraît louche pour un verbe du troisième groupe).

Comment: Et encore, « plussoyer » est plus courant et en concurrence avec « plussoir »...

Comment: Au contraire, je dirais que la recherche **est** lourdement biaisée en faveur de la minorité qui tombent dans les groupes irréguliers. Les [Joubarcqueries](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/482/pourquoi-les-neoverbes-sont-ils-du-premier-groupe/483#comment909_502) sont plus facilement produites par d'admirables fous, du type de ceux qui utilisent *néoverbe*.

Answer (score 7):

On oppose souvent les deux premiers groupes, vivants, au troisième groupe, qui n'est plus productif, dans lequel, comme il a été dit, rentrent divers verbes qui ne correspondent pas aux deux premières conjugaisons.

Pour ce qui est des néologismes, ils sont donc formés, en général, sur le modèle des verbes du premier groupe (majoritairement) ou du second.

On peut chercher derrière cette distinction des nuances de sens, renvoyant aux conjugaisons latines dont ces groupes sont issus :

- Premier groupe en -er (< -ARE latin, qui était déjà majoritaire, et qui a déjà été je crois le plus productif en termes de création de verbes), renvoyant plutôt à des verbes d'action « simples », généralement créés à partir de substantifs;
- second groupe en -ir (<-ESCERE et <-IRE latins), historiquement également employé, notamment pour les verbes créés à partir d'adjectifs, mais désormais de façon extrêmement minoritaire, et de moins en moins,  pour des néologismes, avec la nuance de sens d'une action qui commence à se dérouler, qui est en train de se dérouler (nuance qui est celle des verbes inchoatifs latins en -ESCERE) : grandir, jaunir, et, pour les néologismes, amerrir, alunir, et plus récemment amarsir (mais c'est sans doute l'influence d'atterrir qui a joué ici), rassir, surir,...
  Il paraît d'ailleurs avoir tendance à être remplacé dans ce sens par le suffixe savant en -iser, relevé par Alain Pannetier dans sa réponse (cf. aussi moderniser, féminiser, collectiviser, et modernisation..., plutôt que modernir et modernissage...), et qui a l'avantage d'avoir un équivalent anglais. 
  Fait révélateur, un certain nombre de néologismes en -ir, parfois relevés par les dictionnaires, ont été rejetés par celui de l'Académie. Le Littré de 1872-77 connaît nordir, par exemple.
  Il paraît toutefois avoir encore quelques créations de ce groupe : on trouve ou entend « *mochir » ou « *amochir », en concurrence avec « *mochiser » ou « *amochiser », avec peut-être une préférence pour les premiers (influence d'«enlaidir» ?).

Il y a un billet de blog sur « atterrir, amerrir, alunir »  [là](http://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/atterrir-amerrir-alunir-apponter-1-de-3/), et un court article touchant à la prédominance croissante du premier groupe, Louis-Jean Calvet, « Vers une conjugaison régulière du français? », *Nouvelles Études Francophones*, 20 (2005), p. 9-12.

Answer (score 0):

We encounter a similar phenomenon in German with the so-called weak verbs in particular. Verbs that belong to the German weak verb class all follow a basic, predictable pattern in every verb tense. Tenses are formed using the present infinitive stem. For example, all tenses of the weak verbs hören, sagen, warten are formed using their respective infinitive stems: hör, sag, wart. Weak verbs form the largest group of verbs in German and are the only category that is still expanding in the number of root words it contains. Any relatively modern verbs and all wholly new verbs created in the German language through the creation of new technologies or the adoption of foreign words (e.g., **telefonieren, surfen, downloaden** and so on) are all weak. I guess it makes sense wanting to simplify one's life.