# How to say "voted up" or "voted down" in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, terminologie

I know how you can say that somebody voted *for* something in French:

> Il a voté pour cela.

However, on Stack Exchange sites we have a situation where you can vote something up, or vote it down.  If you vote *for* it, you may have voted it up **or** down.  Is there a way of expressing *vote up* and *vote down* in French?

Comment: En substantifs, il y a aussi _vote de confiance_ — _vote de défiance_.

Comment: [Ce wiki communautaire sur méta](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/214/82) traite de ce genre de questions.

Comment: yes we say "upvoter", when between friends.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Voter pour* et *voter contre* me semblent être les plus appropriés. Éventuellement *voter positivement* et *voter négativement*.

En ce qui me concerne, je préfère anglicir : *upvoter* et *downvoter*.

---

*Voter pour* and *voter contre* is probably the most sensible choice, *voter positivement* and *voter négativement* are acceptable, too.

But I would stick to the anglicisms *upvoter* and *downvoter*.

Comment: +1, et je ne crois pas que l'on ait de meilleure traduction. Seuls les néologismes *downvoter* et *upvoter* me dérangent dans ta réponse, mais c'est une question d'opinion. Ceci dit, je ne les ai entendus que dans des contextes où l'on faisait référence à des sites internet, comme Musicbrainz ou Stack Echange.

Comment: Jamais lu ni entendu parler de "upvoter" et "downvoter" alors que je baigne dans la culture geek... Plussoyer (et moinssoyer dans une moindre mesure) s'emploient assez couramment (et en les écrivant je viens de constater que le dictionnaire inclus dans Firefox les connaît !!).

Answer (score 18):

Je pense que Gilles parlait des termes :

- *Plussoyer* (plus rarement *plussoir*)
- *Moinsoyer*

dans certains de ses commentaires. Ce sont deux néologismes pour indiquer son accord ou son désaccord.

[Entrée du wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plussoyer)

Comment: *Plussoyer* et *moinsoyer*, ou (plus rares, mais je préfère) [plusoir et moinsoir](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/482/pourquoi-les-neoverbes-sont-ils-du-premier-groupe/483#483), sont des néologismes récents, qui s'appliquent spécifiquement aux votes pour des messages sur Internet (+1 de Facebook, Slashdot, Stack Exchange, ...).

Comment: "moinser" est plus usité.

Comment: _Moinsir_ — il faut moanjer moins.

Comment: @Knu : Besoin de deux __s__ ici : "moinsser", il y a aussi "plusser" pour "upvote"

Comment: @Stéphane [les deux sont corrects](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/moinser).

Answer (score 9):

Pourquoi pas « approuver » et « désapprouver » ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas mal, mais ça ne traduit pas l'idée de vote dont parle Jez. Ça ne traduit que la position morale qui est à l'origine de ce vote.

Comment: _réprouver_ est plus drôle

Comment: Dans le cadre des mots existants, on a aussi le couple *louer* / *dénigrer*. Même remarque que Schlubu, mais n'oublions pas que le sens litéral d'un mot peut finir par provenir d'une métonymie, ou autre forme d'analogie.

Answer (score 7):

Pourquoi utiliser des néologismes convenant parfaitement quand on peut utiliser des mots bien français et plus ou moins adaptés ?

- Ascendre — descendre
- Accepter — refuser
- Approuver — réprouver
- Affaiblir — renforcer
- Acquiescer — réfuter
- Appuyer — rejeter
- Adopter — renier
- Confirmer — infirmer
  ...

OK, bon, finalement, les néologismes, ce n'est pas si mal :

- Plus-voter — moins-voter (genre plus-value et moins-value)
- Pourvoter — contrevoter
- Supravoter — infravoter
- Survoter — sousvoter

Ou plus simplement :

- Provoter — antivoter

Et c'est mon dernier mot.

Comment: _plussoyer_ et _moinsoyer_ ont l'avantage d'avoir déjà une certaine existance ailleurs.

Comment: C'est évidant, autent prendre des mots déjà existents. :-)

Comment: J'aime bien *provoter* et *antivoter*.

Comment: Un vote professionnel et un vote antérieur ? :-)

Comment: @Un francophone en fait j'avais d'abord mis _postvoter_ et _antivoter_ dans la liste-pour-rire, et puis je me suis rendu compte qu'il allait mieux avec _provoter_

Comment: Dans la première liste, j'ajouterais apprécier - déprécier.

Answer (score 2):

Personnellement j'opterais pour la paire incrémenter/décrémenter.
Bien que plussoyer soit parfois usité son pendant ne l'est pas donc j'écarterais cette  option.

À choisir je prendrais abonder pour *upvote* et décrémenter (qui a l'avantage d'être neutre) pour *downvote*.

Comment: Si tu choisis "décrémenter" pour "downvote", il faudrait plutôt utiliser "incrémenter" pour "upvote".

Comment: @EricBréchemier et que choisirais-tu pour le pendant d'abonder?

Comment: "s'opposer" peut-être.

Answer (score -1):

Je propose également d'utiliser la racine **-grader** qui me semble à la fois simple et étymologiquement approriée :

- **dégrader** pour *voter moins* semble le plus évident
- Pour *voter plus*, le choix est moins évident. Des pistes : **grader? prograder? aggrader?**

Answer (score -2):

*Approuver* / *rejeter* conviennent et sont corrects.