# Comment dire "to upvote / downvote" en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

> **Cette question est un doublon de**
>   [How to say “voted up” or “voted down” in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-say-voted-up-or-voted-down-in-french)

Le contexte est les forums en ligne, par exemple ici StackExchange ou reddit. Je cherche des verbes pour *to upvote* et *to downvote* : quand on clique sur les petites flèches pour donner des votes positifs ou négatifs à un message.

Comment peut-on dire des choses comme :

> Je t'ai downvoté parce que ...
>
> Vous allez me downvoter mais ...
>
> Quelle question fascinante. Je te upvote !

Comment: Possible copie de http://french.stackexchange.com/q/946/217