# Expression pour "personne unique" (Anglais: "white raven")

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

En Anglais il existe une expression "corbeau blanc" pour signifier "personne unique" (soit: dont on en trouve peu...)

Quelle expression similaire pourrait-on utiliser en Français?

**Plus d'infos sur la signification:**

Je connais "mouton noir" mais celui-ci est assez péjoratif...  Ce que je veux dire est mélioratif...  Donc une personne géniale; une lumière...

Comment: "Sans égale", "sans pareil" ?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi La frontière est assez poreuse entre les qualificatifs évoquant *l'unicité / l'originalité / l'excentricité* et ceux évoquant *l'excellence*, mais avouons que ce n'est pas la même chose. J'ai le sentiment que dire de quelqu'un qu'il est *sans égal* affirme plutôt sa domination d'une discipline que son hétérodoxie.

Comment: @Romain Pour être honnête je ne sais pas vraiment (c'est pour ça que je n'ai pas osé poster une réponse), je ne connais pas assez bien l'anglais pour savoir ce que "white raven" implique. Suivant le contexte "sans égal" ne marchera peut-être pas. J'avoue m'être basé sur le dernier paragraphe de la question.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Tes propositions n'étaient pas absurdes, hein, entendons-nous bien, je voulais simplement préciser. Et tu as raison il y a effectivement, surtout pour *sans pareil*, un usage possible qui correspond très bien, quand c'est utilisé pour signifier que quelqu'un ne ressemble à personne, a son propre style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On dit parfois un **oiseau rare** ou une **perle rare** dans ce sens (principalement) mélioratif. Peut-être moins classique, mais plus proche (littéralement) de ton exemple, mais il me semble aussi avoir rencontré *merle blanc*.

Comment: Déjà un grand merci et un "up-vote" (Quid en Français?) mais je vais attendre encore un peu pour voir si qqn trouve qqc de mieux avant d' accepter finalement...  **;-)**

Comment: C'est une excellente autre question mais... [déjà](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/comment-dire-to-upvote-downvote-en-fran%C3%A7ais) [posée](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-say-voted-up-or-voted-down-in-french) ;-p

Comment: :D La première journée sur french.stackexchange.com... Merci pour le lien vers le duplicata...  J'[en](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13519/expression-pour-personne-unique) avait besoin pour une sollicitation qui demandait des gens bilingues Anglais-Français...
J'ai décidé d'utiliser "merle blanc" puisque celui-ci est plus rare que tes deux autres propositions, donc accepté!!!

Comment: Pour info : je viens de rejeter une proposition d'ajout à ma réponse, parce qu'à mon sens elle différait suffisamment de mes propositions pour constituer une réponse à part entière. J'invite donc la personne (la proposition était anonyme) à la formuler, c'était intéressant.