# Nouveaux verbes français du 2e et 3e groupe

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, néologismes, lexique

On m'a fait remarquer plus tôt que les nouveaux verbes en français étaient dans la très grande majorité du 1<sup>er</sup> groupe. De fait, je n'arrive qu'à trouver très très peu de verbes nouveaux du 2<sup>e</sup> et 3<sup>e</sup> groupe.

Pourrais-je avoir (un lien vers) une liste des nouveaux verbes (i.e. 2006+)  en français du 2<sup>e</sup> et 3<sup>e</sup> groupe ?

Comment: C.f. http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/482/pourquoi-les-n%c3%a9overbes-sont-ils-du-premier-groupe !

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est intéressant, mais bien que cela réponde _en partie_ à ma question, je n'y ai pas pour autant trouvé de liste assez complète.

Comment: Oui oui, ce n'est pas du tout une réponse à cette question. Cela ne fait que corroborer ta remarque.

Comment: La seule liste de verbes nouveaux que je connaisse est celle du *[Dictionnaire des verbes qui manquent*](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/), qui n'a rien d'officiel, qui est un blog participatif, et qui ne comporte que des néologismes.

Comment: Pour quelque chose d'officiel il faut regarder sur [Franceterme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme) mais je crains que ta recherche reste vaine car il se crée peu de nouveaux verbes. Ce sont surtout des noms qui correspondent à des développements technologiques qui se créent. Si on a besoin de verbe on fait une périphrase en employant le nom nouveau avec un verbe déjà existant.

Comment: À vrai dire, tu as trouvé la liste complète. C'est une liste vide. Les seuls nouveaux verbes qui ne sont pas du premier groupe sont soit basés sur un verbe existant (ajout d'un préfixe par exemple), soit des inventions d'une personne qui ne prennent pas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans les usages récents, on peut trouver les classiques déjà cités *amerrir*, *alunir*, *amarsir* mais d'autres moins repérés comme *arrondouillir*, *blanchouillir*, *sortouillir* ou *réfreindre* (en irrégularisation de *réfréner*), et bien sûr mon préféré *orangir*.

Answer (score 5):

Il est vrai que les nouveaux verbes, en français, sont conçus sur le modèle du 1er groupe. Apparemment on ne "fabrique" plus de verbes irréguliers. Le seule verbe récent n'appartenant pas au 1er groupe est, à ma connaissance, le verbe "alunir" appartenant au 2ème groupe. Je n'ai pas eu le temps de vérifier s'il y en a d'autres.

Comment: Et encore, *alunir* n'est pas exactement un néologisme spontané : il calque *atterrir*. Sans cette motivation, on aurait construit un verbe du premier groupe.